# Fully associative and Set Associative TLB operations compared to cache

Tags: caching, arm, paging, tlb, mmu

I was going through the MMU code for an ARM processor(ARMv7). They have made use of fully associative and set associative TLB. I am aware of the implementation of Cache using this method. I also read that TLB is nothing but CPU cache. But I am failing to join the pieces as the purpose of TLB and Cache are different. I would like to know how the set and Full associativity works in context of the TLB.

Comment: _"the purpose of TLB and Cache are different"_  - indeed, in one case you use an address to look up some associated data, whereas in the other case you use an address to look up some associated data. Oh, wait... ;)

Comment: The Slide 27 has a nice block diagram explaining the differences Between a cache and TLB https://www.cs.princeton.edu/courses/archive/fall09/cos318/lectures/VMAddressTranslation.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is globally the same behaviour: TLB use the virtual address and the size as a tag, but instead of storing data, store the attributes of the associative page (Physical address, protection, etc).

Set associative just means that a limited number of pages can share the same tag/attributes, while full associative means that a tag/attribute can be stored at any location in the TLB cache. This is far more efficient, but this can only be done for very small caches.